# How to change popup listView where condition in suitecrm

Tags: suitecrm

i want change list view with different where condition to allow show many rows

i tried with below code in custom/modules/CustomModuleName/views/view.popup.php this file but listViewProcess method doesn't call it call in view.list.php. how to modify in view.popup.php?

```
require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.popup.php');
class vmrfq_VMRFQViewPopup extends ViewPopup
{
    public function listViewProcess(){

        parent::listViewProcess();
        $this->params['custom_select'] = " CUSTOM SELEC";
        $this->params['custom_from'] = "CUSTOM FROM";
        $this->where .= " CUSTOM WHERE CONDITION";
    }
    function listViewPrepare()
    {
        parent::listViewPrepare();
        
    }
    function Customvmrfq_VMRFQViewPopup(){
        parent::ViewPopup();
    }

    function preDisplay(){
        parent::preDisplay();       

    }
```